# Tengo dos tablas tabla1 y tabla2, quiero ingresar los datos de tabla1 en tabla2, pero hay duplicados

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

añadi un nuevo campo a la tabla1 de nombre borrar para marcar los que son duplicados y que se marquen en 1 con el siguiente codigo, pero al eliminarlos e intentar subirlos aun siguen apareciendo duplicados

```
select count(*) from tabla1 where borrar is not null

update tabla1 set borrar = 1
from tabla2 t
inner join tabbla 1 tt on t.id_tipo_identificacion = tt.id_tipo_identificacion and t.nro_identificacion = tt.nro_identificacion
```

la tabla tercero no admite duplicados por PK

Comment: Tu consulta parece correcta, el criterio de registros duplicados es el adecuado? (`id_tipo_identificacion` y `nro_identificacion`. Tabla 2 que pk tiene?

Comment: Patricio la tabla dos no tiene pk, si es el adecuado

Comment: con esta consulta puedo conocer que datos están duplicados entre las dos tablas, en la tabla dos hay un campo de nombre borrar en la cual se asigna un 1 a los duplicados

Comment: la condicion es; si id_tipo_identificacion y nro_identificacion son iguales en las dos tablas, los marque como 1 si no pues serian null